# Как задать привязку к экрану?

Tags: c#

Есть две переменные. Координаты `x` и `у`. Если в x у нас содержится `top`, а в y - `left`, то необходимо выровнять форму в левом верхнем углу. В данный момент я пользуюсь вот таким решением.

```
 this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
 this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
```

Есть ли более простое и элегантное решение?

Comment: а в чём сложность и неэлегантность этого решения?

Comment: То, что вы делаете, выглядит как правильное решение.

Comment: Как сделать для правого нижнего, правого верхнего и т.д

Comment: @Radzhab: С нижним правым сложнее — вам придётся выяснить размер экрана, размер окна и вычесть. Левый верхний удобнее, конечно, для программиста.

Comment: А привязка только к сторонам экрана? Обычно ещё и к окнам делают.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле, всё зависит от того, что вы считаете левым верхним углом. Если верхний левый угол *основного* монитора, то `this.Location = new Point(0, 0);` подойдёт. Но в системе может быть и несколько мониторов.

Если вам нужен левый верхний угол на *самом левом* из мониторов, вам нужно что-то такое:

```
this.Location = Screen.AllScreens
                      .Select(s => s.WorkingArea)
                      .OrderBy(a => a.Left)
                      .First()
                      .Location;
```

---

Для полноты ответа:

Для того, чтобы привязаться к другим краям экрана, придётся подсчитать нужную позицию вручную. Например, для правого нижнего угла:

```
var targetScreen = Screen.PrimaryScreen; // основной монитор
this.Location = new Point(targetScreen.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width,
                          targetScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height);
```

Опять-таки, если вам нужен, например, самый *правый* монитор, вам придётся его *вычислить*:

```
var targetScreen = Screen.AllScreens.OrderByDescending(s => s.WorkingArea.Right).First();
```

---

Без `this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;` не обойтись, если вы хотите сами выставлять координаты окна. «Из коробки» можно только отцентрировать, что вам, очевидно, не нужно.